# Image doesn't display two img src urls

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have working websites and I can't figure out why my images wont display. When I inspect the area and edit html for the `<img src=` it looks like this: `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/parallax/theme/img.php?src=http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/webdevelopment1.jpg&amp;w=175&amp;h=175&amp;zc=1`

You can tell that it has the url twice for the `<img src=`, but why and how can I fix it without changing every single instance of it?

I am using cpanel, phpmyadmin, and wordpress for this site. My siteurl looks correct in wordpress, phpmyadmin, and my permalinks.

UPDATE: here is the html for the single image

`<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/parallax/theme/img.php?src=http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/webdevelopment1.jpg&amp;w=175&amp;h=175&amp;zc=1" alt="Development" width="175" height="175">`

Comment: can you post the complete HTML `<img>` element. Because it doesn't seem to be an issue with duplicated images, your theme has an script to create thumbnail, that's why you see "two" images.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i think this might be plugin conflict or theme outdated that might not compatible with latest version of wordpress, that caused the image not showing.

Check with your theme developer see if they have update coming out, or disable all plugins see image appears.

Comment: I have not updated any plugins in awhile. Almost all of the plugins say they have an update available for download. I still deactivated and checked every plugin with no success. Its possible that the wordpress version has been updated. Is there a way to revert to an old version of wordpress without making a new site?